# I need to create n inverted index and implement spimi

Tags: python, inverted-index

In this code I am first parsing the .sgm file then tokenizing them then stemming them, I want to be able to create an inverted index.  What do I need to add?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

files = ["reut2-000.sgm", "reut2-001.sgm","reut2-002.sgm","reut2-003.sgm","reut2-004.sgm", "reut2-005.sgm", "reut2-006.sgm", "reut2-007.sgm",
         "reut2-008.sgm", "reut2-009.sgm", "reut2-010.sgm", "reut2-011.sgm", "reut2-012.sgm", "reut2-013.sgm", "reut2-014.sgm",
         "reut2-015.sgm", "reut2-016.sgm", "reut2-017.sgm", "reut2-018.sgm", "reut2-019.sgm", "reut2-020.sgm", "reut2-021.sgm" ]
for i in files :

 content = open(i)
 x = content.read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(x,"html.parser")
 documents = soup.find_all('body')

 for document in documents :

    tokens = []

    tokens = tokens + nltk.word_tokenize(str(document))

 stop = stopwords.words('english')

 token = [token.lower() for token in tokens]
 doc =  [ i for i in token if i not in stop ]

 ps = PorterStemmer()
 for w in doc:
    print(ps.stem(w))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as the other introductory help pages.  Specifically, can you please provide illustrative examples of input and desired output?  An inverted index can come in a variety of forms.  Did you merely want to list the references for each word in the text?

Comment: I figured out the inverted index I just want to be able to implement spimi, therefore load inverted index into blocks and when my block is full, write to disk in a json file.